# Minimum Spanning tree different from another

Tags: algorithm, graph, minimum-spanning-tree

Assume we are given

an undirected  graph `g` where every node i,1 <= i < n is connected to all j,i < j <=n

and a source `s`.

We want to find the total costs (defined as the sum of all edges' weights) of the *cheapest* minimum spanning tree that differs from the minimum distance tree of `s` (i.e. from the MST obtained by running prim/dijkstra on `s`) by at least one edge.

What would be the best way to tackle this? Because currently, I can only think of some kind of fixed-point iteration

1. run dijkstra on `(g,s)` to obtain reference graph `r` that we need to differ from
2. `costs := sum(edge_weights_of(r))`
3. `change := 0`
4. for each vertex `u` in `r`, run a bfs and note for each reached vertex `v` the longest edge on the path from `u` to `v`.
5. iterate through all edges `e = (a,b)` in `g`: and find `e'=(a',b')` that is NOT in `r` and minimizes `newchange := weight(e') - weight(longest_edge(a',b'))`
6. if(first_time_here OR `newchange < 0`) then `change += newchange`
7. if(newchange < 0) `goto 4`
8. `result := costs + change`

That seems to waste a lot of time... It relies on the fact that adding an edge to a spanning tree creates a cycle from which we can remove the longest edge.

I also thought about using Kruskal to get an overall minimum spanning tree and only using the above algorithm to replace a single edge when the trees from both, prim and kruskal, happen to be the same, but that doesn't seem to work as the result would be highly dependent on the edges selected during a run of kruskal.

Any suggestions/hints?

Comment: Isn't it very unlikely that those trees are the same anyway? I think you should study under what circumstances the minimum distance tree from `s` is the same as the MST. I would guess those are very specific circumstances (`s` is in the "center" of the graph, whatever that may mean formally).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using Prim`s algorithm

```
Prim's algorithm:
let T be a single vertex x
while (T has fewer than n vertices)
{
    1.find the smallest edge connecting T to G-T
    2.add it to T
}
```

Now lets modify it.

Let you have one minimum spanning tree. Say Tree(E,V)
Using this algorithm

```
Prim's algorithm (Modified):
let T be a single vertex 
let isOther = false
while (T has fewer than n vertices)
{
    1.find the smallest edge (say e) connecting T to G-T
    2.If more than one edge is found, {
        check which one you have in E(Tree)
        choose one different from this 
        add it to T
        set isOther = true
      }
      else if one vertex is found {
        add it to T
        If E(Tree) doesn`t contain this edge, set isOther = true
        Else don`t touch isOther ( keep value ).
      }
}
If isOther = true, it means you have found another tree different from Tree(E,V) and it is T, 
Else graph have single minimum spanning tree
```